# Existe maneira de aninhar um for N vezes?

Tags: python, lista, for

No Python existe algum meio de aninhar um for dentro do outro N vezes? Ou existe algum tipo de algoritmo que simule isto?

Basicamente preciso criar uma função, que realize combinações de valores que estão dentro de sublistas de tamanho 6, porém o número de sublistas é algo variável, no exemplo abaixo simula a ideia de um código que usa um número de sublistas = 2. Caso o número de sublistas fosse = 3, existiriam 3 for aninhados e haveria o `.append(elementosL1,elementosL2,elementosL3)`.

```
combinacoes = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[12,15,16,13,-4,2]]
def criadorCombinacoes(combinacoes):
    listaCombinacoesPossiveis = []
    for elementosL1 in combinacoes[0]:
        for elementosL2 in combinacoes[1]:
            listaCombinacoesPossiveis.append([elementosL1,elementosL2])
    return listaCombinacoesPossiveis
```

Comment: Não entendi seu ponto. Tem algum exemplo do como você desejaria usar essa estrutura?

Comment: Isso me cheira a recursividade, mas realmente não está claro o que quer saber.

Comment: Você precisa gerar todas as combinações possíveis?

Comment: sim,isto e um pedaco de um brute force.

Comment: Se N varia, é caso de recursividade ou algum tipo de empilhamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, e não. Depende do que está querendo fazer.

Se cada nível tem características próprias, praticamente não tem como. Até teria, mas dá tanto trabalho que fazer manualmente fica mais fácil e bonito.

Se todos fazem a mesma coisa então não precisa do que está dizendo, basta adicionar um nível extra de `for` e ele funcionará como esse aninhamento extra. Por exemplo, vamos dizer que você quer percorrer uma matriz onde você não saiba quantas dimensões ela tem. O número de dimensões (`N` de acordo com a pergunta) será avaliado em um `for`, aí cada execução desse laço será uma dimensão da matriz a percorrer, portanto não precisa de aninhar mais que uma vez.

Aí é provável que fazer uma função recursiva seja mais interessante. Algo assim:

Já tem um mecanismo pronto para fazer boa parte do que quer com isto com [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import product 

for i in product(*[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[12,15,16,13,-4,2]]): 
    print(i)
for i in product(*[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[12,15,16,13,-4,2],[123,154,165,136,-41,22]]): 
    print(i)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ArgumentList.py).

Se quer fazer algo próprio é só pegar o fonte desta função para ter uma base.

Fora isto poderia criar um gerador de código, mas duvido que seja necessário, e se for cai no que eu falei inicialmente, dá tanto trabalho que provavelmente fazer o aninhamento manual é mais fácil.

Só lembre que se esse `N` for muito grande pode quase ficar inviável executar isso, ele cria execuções quase infinitas muito rápido porque se torna exponencial, por isso aninhar manual pode ser mais simples em muitos casos.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, se você tem um algoritmo que realmente vai precisar de um número arbitrário de laços um dentro do outro, se usam justamente funções recursivas.

Você coloca um único laço na função recursiva - e, se for necessário, ela chama ela outras  vezes.

Nesse caso, poderia ser:

```
def combine_sequences(sequences, combination=(), result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []

    if not sequences:
        if combination:
            result.append(combination)
        return result

    for element in sequences[0]:
        combine_sequences(sequences[1:], combination + (element,), result)
    return result
```

Então a lógica basicamente é: se a sequência recebida contendo as outras sub-sequências estiver vazia, retorne o resultado atual. A chave é passar para a própria função o resultado parcial das execuções "acima" - no caso a composição `combination + (element,)` .

No caso desse algoritmo, no entanto, é possível fazer de forma interativa também - é só ir guardando os resultados parciais de cada sub-sequência, e para cada elemento na próxima sequência, processar também todos os resultados parciais anteriores. Você só precisa de 2 laços.

```
def combine_seq(seq):
    result = []
    for subseq in seq:
        if not result:
            for element in subseq:
                result.append((element,))
        else:
            new_result = []
            for element in subseq:
                for combination in result:
                    new_result.append(combination + (element,))
            result = new_result

    return new_result
```

E, por fim, novamente, para esse algoritmo específico, bem como alguns outros, o Python tem a função pronta na biblioteca padrão.

O modo `itertools` permite essa (sob o nome de `product`) e varias outras combinações de elementos - no caso:

```
In [230]: import itertools

In [232]: list(itertools.product(*[(1,2), (3,4, 5), (5, 6)]))
Out[232]: 
[(1, 3, 5),
 (1, 3, 6),
 (1, 4, 5),
 (1, 4, 6),
 (1, 5, 5),
 (1, 5, 6),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (2, 3, 6),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (2, 4, 6),
 (2, 5, 5),
 (2, 5, 6)]
```